# Texture not showing up in render preview

Tags: texturing, uv

why does my texture, that I painted in Blender, show up in "Viewport Shading" but not in "Rendered View"? Everything is just grey.[image]

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Fy_OFy_3RwtG8tq7dtzQ5A8-up_wJ_dp

Comment: Please don't make your questions depend exclusively on others downloading the file,  just to understanding what the issue is. Please use the [edit] option at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that show your whole interface and materials and other info that might help us understand your scene and settings.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had a look at your scene file-
1/ You're using 'object' rather than 'UV' in the shader, so it's mapping the image incorrectly.
2/ No idea what has happened to make it invisible, but it is! However I just opened Blender into a default scene, then Appended your object and it shows up fine.

If you get into a mess, just open a default scene and append the objects/lights/whatever. It's a sort-of 'get out of jail free' card...

Comment: The OP did not ask for a critique of his/her faults in the scene, the OP asked for an answer to why the render is apparently not starting.

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen below, you have accidentally paused your rendering, preventing Blender from initializing your render.

[image: Pause Rndering]

Simply unpause it by clicking on the button again. Cheers!